# How to get just a year from jquery datepicker by php?

Tags: php, jquery

I want to `echo` just the year from this date.

```
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({ 
    minDate: -0, 
    maxDate: "+1M +10D" 
  });
});
```

```php
<?php    
  if (isset($_POST['submit']))
  {   
    echo $_POST['datepicker'];
  } 
?>
```

Comment: May be `date('Y', strtotime($_POST['datepicker'];))`?

Comment: thanks @SougataBose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this clientside (through JS) before sending it if you want to, but in PHP you can do it thorugh

```
echo date("Y", strtotime($_POST['datepicker']));
```

- http://php.net/date
- http://php.net/strtotime

Comment: can i select  multple dates in jquery datepicker?

Comment: You can have multiple dates by adding `multidate: true` to the arguments in `datepicker()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve year data in PHP by below example,

```
<?php    
  if (isset($_POST['submit']))
  {   
    $year = date("Y", strtotime($_POST['datepicker']));
    echo $year;
  } 
?>
```